# Conditional Iteration Through Array For Every Element up to the Current Element

Tags: python, iteration

In Python, for a list of numbers I want to append each number that is not less than 12 of the maximum of the series up to that point, and then end the iteration once a number in the series is less than 12 of the maximum. This is what I am trying so far but cannot get the correct results (in the following, all numbers up to the 2nd 1 should be appended):

array = [2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 10, 1, 14, 1, 20, 13, 14, 10, 6, 12]

```
for i in range(len(array)):
       list1 = []
       if not array[i] < (i - 12) in array[0:i]:
           list1.append(array[i])
           print(list1)
```

To try to clarify, I am working through a dataset of prices which are sequential. I want to iterate through the sequence until a number is 12 less than the max of the series up to that point. I then need to end that iteration and begin the same process again, but from the next price in the dataset.

Comment: Explain your problem clearly with the desired output. Currently it’s so confusing

Comment: According to your logic shouldn't your output be `[2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 10, 1, 14, 1]`, since `1 < (14 - 12)` and `14` is the max up to that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if I understood it correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
array = [2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 10, 1, 14, 1, 20, 13, 14, 10, 6, 12]
list1 = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    if (max(array[:i+1]) - array[i] ) <= 12:
        list1.append(array[i])
    else:
        break

print(list1) # Output: [2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 10, 1, 14, 10]
```

Comment: I believe this solves the problem- do you mind walking through the syntax? I am reading this as: if element i of the array subtracted from the max of the iteration is less than or equal to 12 append, else break...

Comment: Sure, so "i" is the index of the current element in the array, in the if statement I check if the maximum element up to the point we are currently at minus the current element is smaller or equal to 12(that's what I understood from your question). If it is, we add it to the results list, if not we break the loop and print the resulting list

Answer (score 1):

Much shorter...

Just a one-liner!!!

Here it is:

```
result = sorted(set(array),key=array.index)[:12]
```

Now:

```
print(result)
```

Is:

```
[2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 10, 1, 14, 20, 13, 6, 12]
```

Comment: I believe the issue here is the use of the set module. The array I am using is a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then I think this should achieve what you want:

```
# added more data to better illustrate solution
array = [2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 10, 1, 14, 1, 20, 13, 14, 10, 6, 12, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 123]
result = []

for i in range(len(array)):

    if(len(result) < 12):
        value = array[i]
        if( not value in result ):
            result.append(value)   
    else:
        break

print('input', array)
print('result', result)
```

Here's a [pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/78576192-6089-4016-b811-8ce8d50406cf/?m=Saved%20fiddle) for you to try